# Can I replace a 48" glass sliding closet door with two 24" doors?

Tags: replacement, closet

Need to replace two broken 48 inch glass sliding doors with 48 inch panel sliding doors but unable to find 48 inch panel sliding closet doors. Possible to attach two 24 inch doors together?

Comment: Try woodworking stores. They often have contacts for obtaining custom-built doors at fairly reasonable prices, and sometimes actually have that service in their catalog.

Comment: In the US, 48" door panels are going to be a specialty item, particularly in a residential setting...to the degree that having them built by a carpenter may be a cost competitive option to a manufactured product.

Answer (score 1):

In my area it is common in rental units to install panel doors in lieu of mirrored doors. We buy the mirrored door track, frame, roller, and hardware kits but with no mirrors. They call it a "knock-down" kit. We then cut wood or composite panels to fit where the glass would go. The manufacturer even gave us a table with net mirror glass dimensions, to use when sizing the wood panels. Check with a local high-volume window and door shop. You might even be able to get the kits from a "big-box" hardware store but I prefer to work with the guys at the sash and door shop for the personal service and expertise.

You might even be able to use your old frame and hardware, measure carefully first, then take apart the frames (they are screwed together) and cut wood panels to fit.

Answer (score 1):

You might try installing 3 - 32" sliding doors in the opening.  This should allow approx. 1" overlap for guides.  2 doors would hang on the rear track with the center door on the front track.  Simple plastic guides aligned to allow the center door to use both guides at the point of overlap travelling from jamb to jamb.  A more involved (optional) guide method.  Slotting the bottom edge of the doors then out of 1" x 1" aluminum "L" metal cut to 2" long secured to the floor for a clean custom look.  The metal should be out of 1/8" thick material and rounded smooth for safety.